# Can't import Jena classes

Tags: eclipse, import, rdf, jena

I'm setting up Jena in eclipse. However, when I try to import any class, such as the Model class, I am getting the error "The import com.hp cannot be resolved". I already set up the build path to the Jena library. Below is a picture of my simple setup and as you can see I am getting an error on the import statement.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMoD2.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package tree starts `org.apache.jena` for Jena version 3 onwards.  Your IDE can help by finding the class `Model`